# How to grey background text of <code> and <pre> elements on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I would like to avoid having to do this every time I post. So, it should probably be part of my theme template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom CSS to your theme without modifying it by going to [Customize](http://www.tumblr.com/customize) -> Advanced.

Hence to add a grey background to your `<code>` you can paste this in the "Add custom CSS" textarea:

```
pre, code {
 background-color: LightGrey;
}
```